# This state will work for the betterment of the common people

Tags: grammar

Question is add modal auxiliary showing 'Obligation'
I had written 
This state need to work for the betterment of common people.
Is this right ?
The options that I thought were must and should

Comment: Welcome to the English Language Learners StackExchange! There's plenty of us who like to answer questions to help people learn English, but that's usually done by giving answers that are more than "*yes*" or "*no*". If you could edit your question to add the alternatives you've considered, why you chose *need* rather than anything else, and any research you've done to try to work this out for yourself, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"Need" does imply obligation, as does "must"; both work fine here.  "Should" isn't quite so obligatory.  "This state should work for the betterment of common people" implies that the state is intended to work for the people, but on occasion fails to do so.  Another good option to consider is "has to."  It also implied obligation, but it's less formal, so be aware of the context of when it is used.

Also, watch out for subject-verb agreement.  You should say "The state *needs*," not "The state *need*."

Comment: "Should" perfectly fine to suggest a recommended course of action, not failure.  *"You **should** apply for that job"*, for example, doesn't imply that you sometimes fail to apply.  But Gita still needs to add more detail to explain what exactly is confusing, otherwise this is just proofreading.

Comment: //Question is add modal auxiliary showing 'Obligation' I had written This state need to work for the betterment of common people. Is this right ? The options that I thought were must and should// It seems to be a question given by the teacher to a student (in India?). The given sentence should be rewritten with an auxiliary verb that shows 'obligation'.  Here, I think the teacher expects "The State should work...." as the correct answer.